# Centered but left-aligned paragraph

Tags: horizontal-alignment, indentation, paragraphs

I want to have a paragraph, that is centered but in itself left-aligned. Does somebody of you know how to achieve this?

(I have text in a paragraph, on each line the text is shorter than the width, but if I just put "flushleft" around it comes to much to the left margin of the page)

Comment: I'm not sure if this is what you want, but how about using `\raggedright` inside a `quote` environment?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It is possible to create a stand-alone environment that can do it all in one - both centering and and internally align elements:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{lipsum}% http://ctan.org/pkg/lipsum
\usepackage{environ}% http://ctan.org/pkg/environ
\NewEnviron​{centerbox}[1][\linewidth]{% \begin{centerbox}[..] ... \end{centerbox}
  \noindent\makebox[\linewidth][c]{%
    \begin{minipage}{#1}%
      \raggedright% Minipage alignment
      \BODY% Typeset body/contents
    \end{minipage}%
  }
}%
\begin{document}
\lipsum[1]

\begin{centerbox}[0.5\linewidth]
  \lipsum[2]
\end{centerbox}

\lipsum[3]
\end{document}
```

​
The above code produces the `centerbox` environment (using the [`environ` package](http://ctan.org/pkg/environ)). An optional argument specifies the width of the centered box, which defaults to `\linewidth`.

[image: Centered box]

Comment: er, the last line of the centered box looks too close to the next line.  a `\strut` at the end would help.  the first line of the box may also be closer than a normal `\baselineskip` but the short line above it is camouflaging the situation.  note that both "last lines" have no descenders; that's a common cause of this problem.

Comment: The `adjustbox` version would be: `\newenvironment{centerbox}[1][\linewidth]{% \begin{centerbox}[..] ... \end{centerbox}
    \begin{adjustbox}{minipage={#1},center}%
      \raggedright
}{%
    \end{adjustbox}%
}%
`. However, I would prefer to simply use the `center` environment here, which also adds the required margin. Note that you can get the same `\makebox` effect with `\leavevmode\hbox to \linewidth\bgroup\hss ... \hss\egroup` which can be split and therefore you can avoid the use of `environ` (which isn't very efficient). Or you use `\Makebox` from my `realboxes` package.

Comment: if you add it all into a minipage-setup, then footnotes and marginpar's wont work anymore, right?

Comment: @Johannes: `\footnote` will produce a minipage-style footnote. However, if you want a footnote at the bottom of the page (outside of the `minipage` environment), you can use a `\footnotemark` (inside the `minipage`) and `\footnotetext` (outside the `minipage) combination. `\marginpar`, however, won't work. I guess you want both to work?

Answer (score 11):

Another approach, using this time the [quoting](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/quoting) package to define a new environment with equal left and right margins (thus, "centered") controlled by an optional argument with a default value of `2em`, and with `\RaggedRight` contents:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{quoting}
\usepackage{ragged2e}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\newenvironment{RCText}[1][2em]
  {\begin{quoting}[leftmargin=#1,rightmargin=#1]\RaggedRight}
  {\end{quoting}}

\begin{document}

\lipsum[1]
\begin{RCText}[2cm]
  \lipsum[1]
\end{RCText}

\lipsum[1]

\end{document}
```

[image]

Here's yet another option, using this time a list environment; again, the margins can be set using the optional argument:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{ragged2e}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\newenvironment{RLCText}[1][2em]
  {\begin{list}{}{\setlength\leftmargin{#1}\setlength\rightmargin{#1}}\item[]\RaggedRight}
  {\end{list}}

\begin{document}

\lipsum[1]
\begin{RLCText}[2cm]
  \lipsum[1]
\end{RLCText}

\lipsum[1]

\end{document}
```

Both solutions admit page breaks inside the new environment.

Comment: With `quoting` v0.1a, one may also add the option `indentfirst=false`.

Answer (score 7):

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{lipsum}% just for filler text

\begin{document}
\begin{center}
    \parbox{0.5\textwidth}{\raggedright\lipsum[1]}
\end{center}
\end{document}
```

You can adapt `0.5\textwidth` to whatever width you like. Note that the text in the `\parbox` won't break onto a new page.

---

Edit: Using `ragged2e`'s `\RaggedRight`, as Mico suggested in [his answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/27977/centered-but-left-aligned-paragraph/27980#27980), instead of `\raggedright` (as I did) is helpful if you want hyphenation in your paragraph, which will result in a more evenly filled paragraph. Here's a comparison of the `\lipsum[1]` filler-text paragraph with `\raggedright` and with `ragged2e`'s `\RaggedRight`:

[image: Comparison of \raggedright and \RaggedRight]

Note how `\RaggedRight` results in one fewer line. (I put boxes around them to make the empty spaces on the right more visible.)

Comment: Nice comparison of the effects of the `\raggedright` and `\RaggedRight` commands!

Answer (score 2):

You could use the `ragged2e` package and its command `\RaggedRight` to make the lines left-aligned. To create a paragraph that's both centered and has a smaller overall textwidth than the surrounding text, you could use the `center` and `minipage` environments. In the following MWE, the default width of this environment is 0.6*`\textwidth`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{ragged2e,lipsum}
\begin{document}
\begin{center}
   \begin{minipage}{0.6\textwidth}
       \RaggedRight
       \lipsum[1] %% filler-text
   \end{minipage}
\end{center}       
\lipsum[2]  %% more filler-text
\end{document}
```

Addendum: If you have need to create several of these centered-raggedright paragraphs, it's helfpul to create a separate environment, say `centragg`, for them. The following MWE illustrates how to set it up and how to use it. Note that the `centragg` environment has a default width of `0.75\textwidth`, but this can be overridden by specifying an explicit width, such as `5cm`. In addition to invoking `\RaggedRight` automatically, it also adds a bit of extra inter-paragraph spacing in case there's more than 1 paragraph at a time in the centragg environment. (Traditionally, paragraphs that are typeset ragged-right have no special paragraph indentation.)

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{ragged2e,lipsum}
\newenvironment{centragg}[1][0.75\textwidth]{% 
   \begin{center}
   \begin{minipage}{#1}
   \RaggedRight \setlength{\parskip}{0.5\baselineskip} \noindent\ignorespaces}
   {\end{minipage}\end{center}}

\begin{document}
\lipsum[2]
\begin{centragg}
   (Default width) \lipsum[2] %% filler-text
\end{centragg}       
\begin{centragg}[6cm]
   (5 cm wide) \lipsum[10] %% filler-text
\end{centragg}       
\lipsum[11]  %% more filler-text
\end{document}
```

The only (?) downside to this approach is that LaTeX will not break `minipage`s (or `parbox`es, for that matter), across pages, risking an overfull page should the centered paragraph be longer than just a few lines.

Comment: Indeed, an this can be easily defined as an own environment as well, i.e. no need for `environ` package.

Comment: Martin: We must have been thinking along similar lines! I was adding a second MWE to show how to put this into a separate environment while you were providing your comment. Notice that my approach does not have the problem of insufficient vertical spacing above and below the paragraphs. :-)