# How to produce such centred effect?

Tags: indentation

I want to put my problem description the way it is done in the image i.e. centred, justified and with a little margin on both sides. I am able to do the rest of math correctly

[image: problem description]

Comment: Related: [Centered but left-aligned paragraph](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/27977/5764)

Comment: A more general question that answers this one: [How can I change the margins for only part of the text?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/588/5764)

Comment: @Werner Looking at the new answers to this question, I think we should indeed close this one as a duplicate.

Comment: @lockstep I don't think this is a duplicate; the other question asks something quite different (the ragged right setting here is definitely not wanted). This is a place where your `quoting` package can be used.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

All you have to do is to put the text "Given a topic ... being redundant." in a `quote` environment:

```
\begin{quote}
  \itshape
  Given a topic ..... being redundant.
\end{quote}
```

Answer (score 2):

KOMA-Script has an `{addmargin}` environment taking a mandatory argument to set both margins and an optional argument to define the different margins.

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}

\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}
\lipsum[1]
\begin{addmargin}{2em}
   \lipsum[2]
\end{addmargin}
\lipsum[1]
\end{document}
```

[image: addmargin]

But I recommend to define a now environment in terms of logical markup (your text seems not to be a quote …). With such a defined environment later changes are easy and can be made consistently.

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}

\usepackage{lipsum}

\newenvironment{definition}{%
    \addvspace{\baselineskip}%
    \begin{addmargin}{3em}%
        \itshape\noindent
}{%
    \end{addmargin}%
    \vspace{\baselineskip}%
}

\begin{document}
\lipsum[1]
\begin{definition}
   \lipsum[2]
\end{definition}
\lipsum[1]
\end{document}
```

[image: definiton]

Furthermore there are [some packages](http://www.ctan.org/topic/maths-theorem) offering a better interface to define theroem like environments …

Answer (score 1):

Just for the record since I myself use `quote` for this.

If you want increase the margins just as the paragraph indentation (`\parindent`) a simple solution without environments is `{\narrower .... }`. Aside from personal preferences about what markup is more clear, with this method is easy increase the margin x2, x3, etc. times the paragraph indentation, but a `\st{`*disavantage*`}` "feature" of this command is that in tests without any indentation  (`\setlength{\parindent}{0em}`) the "quotes" are just as normal text.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{lipsum,xcolor}
\setlength{\parskip}{2ex}
\setlength{\parindent}{1em}
\begin{document}
\lipsum[2] % normal margin
{\em\color{blue}\narrower \lipsum[2]} % margin + parindent (+1em)
\lipsum[2] % normal margin
{\narrower\narrower\narrower\em\color{red} \lipsum[2]}% (+ 6em)
\lipsum[2] % normal margin 
\end{document}
```

[image: MWE]

Comment: Rather than using `\narrower`, which is a foreign command to LaTeX (and can give unexpected results), I would suggest the `quoting` package that allows for easy customizations.

Comment: @egreg, although I 'm not aware of such unexpected results, I repeat: Just for the record :-)

Comment: Try using a list environment in your `\narrower` setting.